# tbody doesn't respect width property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table in html that I want to format fairly specifically, so that the  columns all have equal width.  To do so, I set `table-layout: fixed;` in the .css file and give each column a width equal to 25% (there are four of them).  The table itself also has a fixed width, in pixels.  This seems to work fine.

But then I have a button that uses javascript to flip the table between `display: none;` and `display: block;`.  Upon toggling the table back to block, the columns have resized to be squished in the left hand side.  Looking at Firefox's inspector thingy, it looks like the browser is inserting a  `<tbody>` element, and it is this that is being redrawn a different size.  Putting a `width: 100%;` for the tbody element in the .css file doesn't resolve the issue.

So if anyone can tell me whats going on here and how to resolve it, that'd be great.

ETA: Also, I reproduced this behavior in both Firefox and Chrome, so I don't think its just a browser bug.

Comment: Have you inspected the display value prior to pressing your button? Perhaps it isn't block. If it is, it might be best to edit your post to include your code, simplified as much as possible while still reproducing your error.

Comment: Of course it isn't a browser bug - it is _specified behavior_ since good old HTML 4.01 times (or maybe even before, can't be bothered to check now.)

Comment: @BenRhodes: Ah, you got it.  I knew table elements had their own display property, but didn't realize the table as a whole did.  So I was unwittingly changing from table to none to block.  Thanks so much.

Comment: display:table; Without code is hard to answer